# Element with higher z-index is still on the background of another elements

Tags: css, css-position, z-index, headless-ui

Here is me trying to hover over 'delete' popup button positioned `absolute` relatively to three dots to the left.

[image]

As you can see it ignores the delete button completely, even though I even explicitly added a higher z-index to it. It has the same effect with any other elements on the background, so I estimate that problem is somewhere in code relevant to 'delete' button and it's popover. There are no elements with `sticky` or `fixed` positioning in this project. Here is my JSX with TailwindCSS and Headless UI's Popover component:

```
Relative part of parent component.

<Disclosure.Panel className="w-full text-gray-900 flex flex-col" >
        {projects?.map(project => Object.keys(project).map(key => (
          <div className={`w-4/5 py-2 hover:font-medium cursor-pointer self-end pl-2 flex items-center justify-between ${selectedProject === key ? 'bg-gray-900 text-gray-50 font-medium' : ''}`} onClick={() => handleSelect(key)} key={key}>
            <p>{key}</p>
            <Popover className='relative z-100'>
              <Popover.Button className='flex items-center'><EllipsisHorizontalIcon className='w-8 h-6 pr-2 hover:text-zinc-400'/></Popover.Button>
              <ProjectSettingsPopover selectedProject={selectedProject} />
            </Popover>
          </div>
        )))}
        <div className="flex gap-2 h-7 mt-2 w-4/5 ml-auto">
          <input type='text' className='w-4/5 bg-background rounded-md px-2 py-1 text-sm border-2 border-grayDark' placeholder='New Project' value={input} onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}></input>
          <button className='bg-black p-1 rounded-full flex items-center justify-center hover:bg-zinc-700' onClick={() => handleNewProject()}><PlusCircleIcon className='text-primary h-5 w-5 group-hover:text-primaryDark'/></button>      
        </div>
</Disclosure.Panel>
```

```
ProjectSettingsPopover.js
return (
    <Transition
        enter="transition ease-out duration-200"
        enterFrom="opacity-0 -translate-x-1"
        enterTo="opacity-100 -translate-x-0"
        leave="transition ease-in duration-150"
        leaveFrom="opacity-100 -translate-x-0"
        leaveTo="opacity-0 -translate-x-1" 
        appear 
    >
        <Popover.Panel className="left-9 -top-8 w-24 text-sm z-50 rounded-sm flex flex-col absolute bg-background shadow-lg ring-1 border border-black ring-black ring-opacity-5">
            <Button btnStyle='default' btnSize='edgy' onClick={deleteProject}>delete</Button>
        </Popover.Panel>                    
    </Transition>
  )
```

What is the reason of such a weird behavior?